# Ways to help optimise a SQL update join

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I'm a relative newbie to SQL so apologies if this question is dumb! I have the following query and it is running very very slowly. Last time I tried it also created such a large log file that it filled the drive with the log file on and so threw an error before completing the query. I'd just like some simple tips please on how this can be optimised or pointers towards any useful resources I can follow.
Many thanks in advance!

```
alter table Recalc_tmp1
add   [Fraction1] float,
      [Fraction2] float
go
update Recalc_tmp1
set [Fraction1] = case when b.[Numerator1] <> 0 then cast(b.[Numerator1] as float)/cast(b.[Denominator1] as float) else null end,
    [Fraction2] = case when b.[Numerator2] <> 0 then cast(b.[Numerator2] as float)/cast(b.[Denominator2] as float) else null end
from Recalc_tmp1 a
left join WriteDowns b
on a.ID1 = b.ID1 AND a.ID2 = b.ID2 AND a.ID3 = b.ID3
```

I've changed some field names, they are more logical in my actual data!
The `WriteDowns` table is relatively small but the `Recalc_tmp1` table is huge (tens of millions of rows) i.e. not all entries in the `Recalc_tmp1` table have a match in the `WriteDowns` table.
ID1 is indexed on both tables

I originally had this as a `select.. into` join query but when comparing that and this `update` join option using the execution plans, the `select into` option was twice as slow.

Comment: I think you meant to check if Denominator1 and Denominator2 are not zero. Also, if ID1 is the primary key in both tables why are you also checking ID2 and ID3?

Comment: Why use a left join if you are using values from b to populate a and is left as null other wise. Change it to an inner join and your query would run much faster with the expected results

Comment: @DavidN - You're right, the ID1 columns aren't in fact primary keys. But they are indexed in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
;with WriteDowns_cte as
(
select ID1, 
    case when [Denominator1] <> 0 then cast([Numerator1] as float)/cast([Denominator1] as float) end [Fraction1],
    case when [Denominator2] <> 0 then cast([Numerator2] as float)/cast([Denominator2] as float) end [Fraction2] 
from WriteDowns
)
update Recalc_tmp1
set [Fraction1] = b.[Fraction1],
    [Fraction2] = b.[Fraction2]
from Recalc_tmp1 a
join WriteDowns_cte b
on a.ID1 = b.ID1
```

Answer (score 1):

Obvious thing is to make the LEFT join an INNER join.  Unless you need to update the rows in Recalc_tmp1 that don't have a corresponding match in WriteDowns?
This is also the reason the log file grew so much.  It was having to write a log record for updating every row of the tens of millions.
If you do need to update all the rows then you'll need to find a way to run multiple update statements each updating some fraction of the table.  Making sure to only run one at a time and make sure any transactions are committed before starting the next batch.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation on the cause helped